# Configuring HP Smart Switch and SonicWall with VLAN

Tags: vlan, dhcp, hp, sonicwall, dell

I'm trying to configure an HP SmartSwitch with a Dell SonicWall on a VLAN for some computers in our network.

The computers in question are on port 37 on the switch. I've created a new VLAN interface on the SonicWall, tagged it ID 2. Then created a new DHCP server on the SonicWall and linked it to the new X0:V2 interface creating a subnet of IPs.

Then on the HP I have tried multiple ways to configure the VLAN. I've created a new VLAN ID 2. Then in the Participating page I've Excluded port 37 from the main VLAN, 1. Then I've tried both tagged and untagged for port 37 in the VLAN 2 area.

When 37 is tagged and I check config it shows port 37 as "none"

[image]

But when it's untagged for VLAN 2 it shows it as VLAN ID 2. However, no matter whether it's tagged or untagged for VLAN 2, I never get an IP on my laptop and it never has network connection.

I've tried on my laptop to set a static IP in the new subnet, still no network connection.

The firewall is a Dell SonicWall TZ 300. And switch is an HP V1810-48G.

Below are screenshots of my config. What am I missing here to make this tag correctly? I've got another 5 ports to make this work on, but I can't get it going.

Switch Config:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Firewall config:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to tag the frames between the firewall and switch so that the switch knows which frames are for which VLAN. The access interfaces to the hosts need to be untagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a host is connected to port 37 you need to configure it *untagged* for VLAN ID 2. Hosts don't usually tag.

Also, some other port needs to participate in VLAN 2 to have a working network. Likely, you'll want to add VLAN 2 as *tagged* on the port linking to the SonicWall (so the link is a VLAN trunk). And don't forget to configure VLAN 2 as tagged on the SonicWall itself on the interface towards the switch.

Forget the switch's (somewhat misleading) *VLAN -> VLAN Ports* menu - it's just for configuring priorities for QoS. All you need is *VLAN -> VLAN Configuration* to create a VLAN and *Participation/Tagging* to configure tagged and untagged VLANs on the required ports.